# Miigrating from Red-Shift to Snowflake-- converting unload in RedShift to copy into stage

Tags: amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am migrating code from RedShift to Snowflake and encountered ESCAPE command in Red Shift.
When I am trying to convert this to compatible snowflake, I am not sure if it will work correctly.

The statement in RedShift is Just ESCAPE

Can someone please throw some insights or what should be the corresponding statement in Snowflake?

Comment: What is the context of the ESCAPE keyword showing up? Is the entire statement submitted to redshift just "ESCAPE"? The only documentation I can find for `ESCAPE` as a keyword in redshift is with the `LIKE` operator to define an escape character.

Comment: I thought Raja means the `ESCAPE` keyword to the `COPY` command.  As it is, the question is unclear and by that cannot currently be answered.

Comment: Here's sample code, The red shift is doing unload to S3 from table and the new objective is to have a similar code for snowflake to copy data from snowflake table and write it to stage.......

Comment: @JNevill 
Red shift

unload (query) to 'path.filename.dat'
 --iam_role 
 'arn:aws:iam::XYZ'
 --iam_role 
 'arn:aws:iam::PQR'
 iam_role 'iamrole'
DELIMITER 'delim' filetype ALLOWOVERWRITE
 ENCRYPTED
KMS_KEY_ID 'KMSKEY'  
ESCAPE  NULL AS '\NA'  
 parallel off

Comment: Need help to migrate the above query.. Here is my sample codeSnowflake

COPY INTO path.filename.dat FROM 
(query)
file_format=(FIELD_DELIMITER = 'delim'  ESCAPE ='\\' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\' NULL_IF = ('NULL','/NA') 
            )
include_query_id=true;

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has file format information that you can use with your data files.  That format can contain an alternate escape character specification (other than backslash).  See: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions and look at the "escape" parameter.